# CSS title underline without the text part

Tags: html, css

Maybe this has been answered before but I haven't found a proper solution for my question on SO.

Ok, here goes:

I need to underline an `h3` tag with 100% EXCEPT for the part where the actual text is. like so:

**My super title
                 ____________________________________________________**

This has to be 100% width, so something like

```
h3:after {
        content:"\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0";
}
```

with fixed number whitespaces wouldn't work.

Also the tag has to be *pure*. Meaning it is not surrounded with DIVs or span etc... (User submitted content from wysiwyg) It's just an h3 tag.

Is this possible in css3 at all? If not I'm willing to add some js to make it work.

UPDATE:

Here's a screenshot with expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you add screen with the result expected?

Comment: My super title ________________________________

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try in this way:

Markup

```
<h3>A 100% wide title</h3>
```

CSS

```
h3 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: .5em;
  border-bottom: 1px #767676 solid;
}
```

Example: http://cdpn.io/Awpef

---

Resulting effect

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Do you know how cross-browser this solution is?

Answer (score 0):

Like this? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UeS2j/1/)

```
    h3:after {
    content:"";

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: -20px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
h3 {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
h3:after {
    content:'';
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4KqNF/)

Answer (score 0):

Without using the `:after` pseudo element, you could do this:

```
<div id="wraptitle"><h3>A Second Title</h3></div>
```

CSS

```
#wraptitle {
    border-bottom : 1px solid black;
    position : relative;
}

#wraptitle h3 {
    display : inline;
    position : relative;
    bottom : 0;
    border-bottom : 1px solid white; /* white is actually the background color */
    padding-right : 10px;
}
```

Make sure margin of the `h3` element is set to `0`, or its border wouldn't go over it.

A live example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/JYNn5/

Comment: It works but OP asked for solution whitout extra surrounding markup